# Scan WiFi MAC addresses of mobile phones from java application

Tags: java, wifi

My application (not mobile application) needs to scan WiFi MAC addresses of mobile phones that are in my range.

For now I can only test it with my laptop. So I would like to connect my wireless card in laptop with my java application so application could scan for addresses. In near future, I will connect my application with different WiFi detector.

My WiFi card is Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection

Stackoverflow and google only shows results for android mobile development.

What API can you recommend?

Comment: ...and your question is what, exactly?

Comment: hmm I read my post again and I realized that I didn't specified my question :(, sloppy. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky and maybe impossible, depending on precisely what you want - feel free to view this as a list of warnings or starting points, depending on how brave you feel :)

- to obtain MAC addresses you need to capture raw packets, which isn't possible using pure Java; you'll need to use something like [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) which wraps the (native) [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) packet sniffing library
- to determine whether a MAC address is likely to belong to a mobile phone, you'll need the list of [Organizationally Unique Identifiers](http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/oui.txt) which links the first three bytes of a MAC address with the device manufacturer; mind that the OUI list might not be sufficient, since Apple (for instance) makes phones *and* other devices
- to see all wireless traffic you'll need a driver that supports putting the wifi interface into monitor mode - these don't exist for all platforms/devices
- the devices may not be sending any data...

Comment: Nothing is impossible :) (or it is in this case heh) I read somewhere that Phyton can do that but your answer is helpful because I think I'll give up from java in this case.